# How can I merge Sentiment Analysis Results from different sources?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I have a text I want analyze and send it to several Sentiment Analysis APIs and store the result of them. This text can be a tweet for example.

In the **training phase**, a human defines the real sentiment of the text and the APIs with the same answer get a better ranking. The machine also analyzes the Main Topic of the Text.

In the **Use phase**:
The machine receives a text, analyzes the Main Topic of the text, says which APIs worked best for that topic and merges these best APIs results based on their rating.

I thought about something like a recommendation engine like [prediction.io](http://prediction.io/)

Is this the best way to solve the problem?
What technologies can I use?

Comment: This is an example of an ensemble learning problem

Comment: on what metrics you are determining which API worked best for the topic? Are you calculating f score, precision, recall etc for each result?